# Daily CPU spikes bring site down

Tags: performance, hosting, digitalocean

Over the past month or so we have been getting a daily CPU spike which is killing our Craft 3.7.59 site. It happens between 9pm and 10pm GMT each night and doesn't seem linked to any increase in traffic.

The site is hosted on Digital Ocean and we have moved to a new Droplet, restarted everything & redeployed everything. We have a daemon to run the queue but it doesn't look like this is busier than usual at this time.

[image]

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Could Craft be running a daily process around this time which is using up the server resources?

Many thanks,
Malcolm

Comment: Are you running any cron jobs at that time, like nightly backups?

Comment: Thanks @MoritzLost - we do run a nightly backup up but this happens much later in the night. I can see the I/O spike when this happens but it doesn't effect the CPU usage.

Comment: cron jobs would be the first suspect, but since that isn't it, I'd check the web server access logs around that time to see if there was an actual spike in web server traffic around that time.